# Rewrite equation to pass "performs a multiplication on the result of a division" on slither

Tags: solidity, math, slither

I am using slither and I get the following medium severity error: performs a multiplication on the result of a division

Now this is the equation in question.

```
uint256 mult = (_type == 1 ? 5 : 2);
uint256 value = (((_amount / 1e18) * (getPrice() / 1e18)) / 10) * mult * 1e18;
```

I need some help to rewrite this equation to satisfy slither.

That equation is basically doing the following:

- Gets the price of what they sent (`getPrice` is the current price of BNB and `_amount` is what they sent in wei)
- Get the value of how many times it goes into $10
- Multiply that value by a multiplier
- Convert it back to wei
- Gives answer on how many tokens to give to user

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this actually works and is much cleaner.

```
uint256 value = ((_amount * getPrice() * mult) / 10e18);
```